# How to fix issue "Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER" with JMeter and Firefox

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I have installed the JMeter and Firefox. when I'm recording the script it is throwing an `Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER` and I have installed the certificate in both Firefox as well as in the system

I"m using windows Machine and working on JMeter tool. Freshly installed JMeter and Firefox and installed the certificate in both machine as well as on the browser but event then it is throwing an `Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to install JMeter Certificate in Windows system storage, just in browser.

So, check that you have done every step:

1. Remove all old certificates from browser and windows.
2. Press Start record in [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#script-recorder).
3. Install new just created certificate in your browser (ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt located in your JMeter bin directory).
4. Do actions with your web application to record requests.

[image]

**How to remove old and add new certificates in Firefox:**

1. Start Firefox
2. Open menu
3. Options
4. Privacy & Security
5. View Cerificates
6. Ensure there are no certificates with names "_DO NOT INSTALL..", "DO NOT INSTALL..", "JMETER.." and other related to JMeter cerificates, or Delete them if they present.
7. Click Import.
8. Navigate to your JMeter bin dir and choose ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt file.
9. **Check Trust this CA to identify websites.**
10. Press Ok

[image]

Comment: Greate! Did you get what was wrong with your scenario?

Comment: Yes, I get what I'm looking for. Thank you for that,  can you please help me, what is the meaning of that checkbox "Trust this CA to identify websites".

Comment: Good! You may mark this answer as a Correct Answer and vote for it.
  
Trust this CA to identify websites — thats mean you trust this fake JMeter created certificate.

Comment: Actually, if your (or fake JMeter certificate in our case) manually created certificate doesn't chain up to a trusted root, then Firefox rise 'SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER' error.

Comment: So,  "Trust this CA to identify websites" — thats mean you trust this fake JMeter created certificate.

Comment: @surenderpal If you question is resolved you may mark this answer as a Correct Answer and vote for it. Thanks!

Comment: I have done the same can you please tell me how to authenticate OAuth in JMeter, I have watched more than 10 videos of authentication from youtube, but the issue is still open, help me, please!!  i have edited the question and uploaded the pic, can you a look on it.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211607/while-performing-load-testing-on-sharepoint-app-it-shows-error-for-winauth-how

Comment: Ok, I'll look your question