# JMeter 4.0 | java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0

While recording a through **HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder** the browser is showing below error when URL for the website is navigated.

```
**java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.LazySchemeSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazySchemeSocketFactory.java:97)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:318)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:114)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:697)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:455)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:235)**
```

How do I resolve this issue to get the script recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update to JMeter last verions (5 for now). It's highly recommend that most users run the [latest release](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi).
2. Check your proxy connection. If you are testing from a proxy, you need to set up your proxy server host and port in JMeter.
   To do so run the `jmeter[.bat]` file from a command line with the following parameters:

   > -H [proxy server hostname or ip address]
   >   -P [proxy server port]
   >   -N [nonproxy hosts] (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
   >   -u [username for proxy authentication - if required]
   >   -a [password for proxy authentication - if required]

   Example:

   ```
   jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost
   ```
3. Set up JMeter certificate, follow steps from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54198897/5938853

Check this for more information:

- [Recording with JMeter Proxy](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording/)
- [JMeter proxy server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)